# Unstoppable Blue Screen of Death

Tags: windows

Hey guys I'm trying to fix my friends computer running windows 7. No matter what I do, start repairing, safe mode, boot from windows cd, anything it will always go to the BSOD, I can't get anywhere. I almost need to completely wipe the harddrive or something and start from scratch, I've never encountered a problem like this, usually safe mode or booting from disk works. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error that BSOD shows??

Comment: While I agree with paxdiablo's feeling on windows, I do want to help. To do that we need to know which error windows throws via the BSOD. If it reboots quickly try to catch it on a video, then transcribe that. Alternatively, get the disk out of the non-booting computer and put it in a working one. Then check disk and virus scan. (Hopefully needless to say. Make sure that that second computer is up to date **before** you do that.)

Answer (score 1):

To start troubleshooting, Use F8 just after the bios post and before Windows starts to load, select "disable automatic restart on system failure", the bsod should stay up now. Copy and post the entire message in an Edit of your question.

.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Could be a memory related problem.  This would cause seemingly random BSODs.  Get a live cd that has memtest86+ (many linux live cds have it) and run that to test the ram.  This will either verify that the memory is the problem or eliminate it as a possibility.  If the memory is the problem, its an easy fix - buy new memory.

Comment: There is also a memory tester on modern windows CDs. Sadly all of them do not guarantee that the memory is fine. They can show faults, but the absence of faults merely means none was detected. Not that none are present.

Answer (score 1):

Stop 0x00000050

- The BCCode 50 usually occurs after the installation of faulty hardware or in the event of failure of installed hardware (usually related to defective RAM, be it main memory, L2 RAM cache, or video RAM).
- Another common cause is the installation of a faulty system service.
- Antivirus software can also trigger this error
- As can a corrupted NTFS volume.

Solutions for some of these:

1. Fix the NTFS volume. Either by one the broken system, or connect the drive to another computer (e.g. put it in an external enclosure).
2. Check the memory (e.g. use mentest86)
3. If you installed any new hardware just before this error occurred, remove that new hardware.
4. Check the computer for malware. See amongst others [this link on this site](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc/)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a hardware problem, typically a memory problem where its either bad or the memory contacts are not seated well, that's generating random crashes. To test if its hardware or software, try booting a LiveCD version of any of the Linux versions. This will boot from the CD, and bring up a full OS where you can also run some hardware diagnostics.